# Retrieving data from PostgreSQL and importing it as layer in QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql, qgis-python-console

I am trying to write a piece of code to query and then import a subset of a PostgreSQL as a vector layer onto the map.

I am able to connect and add the whole SQL table into QGIS. But I am not sure how to query the table; for a subset using `ST_Intersect()` to a bounding box before adding it as a layer into the map.

This is where I am at

```py
import psycopg2 
from psycopg2 import sql
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
try:
    uri.setConnection('host', 'port', 'name', 'user', 'pass')
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} Where st_intersects(lockgeom, st_transform((ST_MakeEnvelope(-121.860102, 37.387439, -121.860510,
37.385896, 4326)), 2163))").format(sql.Identifier("cuebiq", "usca_trip_points7_201905"))

uri.setDataSource("schema","table name","lock_geom",a.Sql='query', aKeyColumn='id')
uri.setKeyColumn('id')
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"mylayernamep","postgres")
#vlayer=ST_Intersects(lockgeom, st_transform((ST_MakeEnvelope(-121.860102, 37.387439, -121.860510,
37.385896, 4326)), 2163))
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print ("invalid")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer, True)
```

Comment: Try : `uri.setDataSource("", query, ...`

Comment: I tried uri.setDataSource("cuebiq","usca_trip_points7_201905","lock_geom","query", aKeyColumn='id')
it still creates an empty layer , Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Not exactly, just let an empty schema and replace table name by the query text : `uri.setDataSource("", "SELECT * FROM ...", "lock_geom" ...`. Or create a view under PostGIS and load it.

Comment: I tried : 
query= sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} Where st_intersects(lock_geom, st_transform((ST_MakeEnvelope(-121.860102, 37.387439, -121.860510, 37.385896, 4326)), 2163))").format(sql.Identifier("cuebiq", "usca_trip_points7_201905"))
cur.execute(query)
myresult = cur.fetchone()
print(myresult)
uri.setDataSource("","query", "lock_geom" , aKeyColumn='id')

Comment: And also  uri.setDataSource("","SELECT * FROM {} Where st_intersects(lock_geom, st_transform((ST_MakeEnvelope(-121.860102, 37.387439, -121.860510, 37.385896, 4326)), 2163)).format(sql.Identifier("cuebiq", "usca_trip_points7_201905"))", "lock_geom" , aKeyColumn='id')

Comment: Your query object must be string type, with the PostGIS query as text. and after, put `query` object in the `uri.setDataSource` with an empty schema and don't quote the `query` object. If you type query text directly, you quoted the `format`, so it's an error.